# how to echo lastly inserted records from mysql database?

Tags: php, mysql

I am creating a question and answer system. How to echo the lastly inserted records to a php page.

Following is my table structure.

[image]

**update**

thanks for the help

Comment: you could have added something like a `created_at` timestamp column and sorted it descending and get the first row, and thats it

Answer (score 0):

From what you've written, it seems like the lastInsertId() method may be what you're looking for. A good example of this can be found at: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert_lastid.asp

Answer (score 0):

As you have an autoincrement field (qid), the last inserted record will hold the highest number. So just use a subselect with `MAX()` something like

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3  FROM tablename  WHERE qid=(
    SELECT max(qid) FROM tablename
)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use mysqli_insert_id() function to get last inserted record is and select data with that reference,
OR 
do query like 
select * FROM table name LIMIT 0,1 ORDER BY id DESC
you can get last data

Answer (score 0):

You can use ORDER BY using qid DESC. Example:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM your_table ORDER BY qid DESC LIMIT 1";
```

This query will return last inserted row to you with all the data.

Comment: thanks its working fine now , appreciate your help  !

Comment: Glad to know that.